# How to get the reason of a ban spaced in the confirmation message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So whenever a user gets banned by the ban command from my Discord.js bot, the reason that gets specified behind the user mention isn't getting spaced in the confirmation message. I've stored the ban reason in the following code: `const banReason = args.slice(1).join('');` and used it in the message as ``` .addFields({ name: 'Reason', value: ``${banReason}`` }) ```. But whenever the bot returns the message, all of the text that is the ban reason doesn't get spaced. For example, if I would be to enter `-ban @User No spacing` it would show the reason in the confirmation message as `Nospacing`. So the question is how do you space the ban reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I give you the answer, I'd like to give you a little 'lesson' about `.join()`

The `.join()` method is used in order to join together the elements of an array.

```
// For example, if we take the following array and use the join method on it, we'll get:
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon'];
fruits.join();
// Expected Output: 'apple,orange,watermelon'
// .join() automatically defaults the joining to have ',' between the elements if no argument was provided.
```

Although in some cases we'd obviously want to separate the elements in a different way, that would look a little bit cleaner. Here we can pass a certain argument that would separate the elements from each other.

```
// For example:
fruits.join('');
// Expected Output: 'appleorangewatermelon'
```

From here, since your arguments are basically an array of elements the user has given, we can simply join them with a spacing using:

```
fruits.join(' ');
// Expected Output: 'apple orange watermelon'
// from this, we learn that the answer to your problem is: args.slice(1).join(' ');
```

Good luck!

Comment: Well, I definitely understand the .join() method now thanks to you, appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem!! :p

Answer (score 1):

You have to make

```js
const banReason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
```

as you want to have spaces in between words. Your mistake was simply that you joined nothing.